# Inserting JQUERY value into hidden field of html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to insert a cookie value which I am getting by using jQuery.

I want to grab the value of the cookie and insert it into the html `value` attribute.

```
<input id="visitorcookie" type="hidden" value="<script>$.cookie('visitorCookie');</script>" name="com.silverpop.iMAWebCookie">
```

Is this correct how I am doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all actually. The `value` attitribute won't execute any code, it just can store a value.

Do this: when the DOM is ready, select the hidden field by ID with `$('#visitorcookie')` and set it's value with `.val()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#visitorcookie').val($.cookie('visitorCookie'));
});
```

More about:

- [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#visitorcookie").val($.cookie('visitorCookie'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#visitorcookie').val($.cookie('visitorCookie'));`